# why does entry textvariable remain empty after I type something in it

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

textvarible that is created in click function for entry box is not printing any thing in function `d`. i.e on call to function `d()`, `a.get()` is empty. Why is this not printing?

I tried threading these two `click()` and `d()` function, but nothing works

```
from tkinter import *

def click():
    def d():
        print(a.get())


    w2=Tk()
    a=StringVar()
    E=Entry(w2,textvariable=a).pack()
    b=Button(w2,text="submit",command=d).pack()

w=Tk()  
b=Button(w,text="ok",command=click).pack()
mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a problem with multiple instances of `Tk()`. See [Why are multiple instances of Tk discouraged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045401/why-are-multiple-instances-of-tk-discouraged/48045508#48045508) Instead open the second window as `Toplevel()`:

```
w2 = Toplevel(w)
```